# URLImage in InfiniteScrollAdapter in Simulator shows NPE (CodenameOne)

Tags: java, codenameone

My app features an `InfiniteScrollAdapter` populated with images through `URLImage` and `URLImage.ImageAdapter`.

In the simulator (Iphone3GS or Xoom or GoogleNexus7), and NPE is shown the first time the `InfiniteScrollAdapter` appears, although the file does exist on the server.

**Please note : In this test there was only one entry in the database. So on the image below what you should see is the same row (image + text) duplicated 3 times.**

[image: NPE in InfiniteScrollAdapter]

Please note that the order in the undisplayed icon can differ

[image: NPE with different order in the undisplayed icons]

The code I used to download the image is :

```
Image tempPlaceholder = Image.createImage(
            ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX,
            ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX,
            ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
    Graphics gr = tempPlaceholder.getGraphics();
    gr.setAntiAliased(true);
    gr.setColor(ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
    gr.fillArc(0, 0, ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX, ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX, 0, 360);

    EncodedImage roundPlaceholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tempPlaceholder, true);

    final Image reportImage = URLImage.createToStorage(
                            roundPlaceholder,
                            photoFilenameInStorage,
                            currentReport.getPhotoPath(),
                            ParametresGeneraux.RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK
                    );
```

And here is the overridden imageAdapter method :

```
    public final static URLImage.ImageAdapter RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK = new URLImage.ImageAdapter() {
    @Override
    public EncodedImage adaptImage(EncodedImage downloadedImage, EncodedImage placeholderImage) {
        final Image[] tmp = new Image[1];

        if (!Display.getInstance().isEdt()) {
            // The image scaling has to be called from EDT
            Display.getInstance().callSeriallyAndWait(() -> {

                tmp[0] = downloadedImage.scaledLargerRatio(placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight());
                if (tmp[0].getWidth() > placeholderImage.getWidth()) {
                    int diff = tmp[0].getWidth() - placeholderImage.getWidth();
                    int x = diff / 2;
                    tmp[0] = tmp[0].subImage(x, 0, placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight(), true);
                } else if (tmp[0].getHeight() > placeholderImage.getHeight()) {
                    int diff = tmp[0].getHeight() - placeholderImage.getHeight();
                    int y = diff / 2;
                    tmp[0] = tmp[0].subImage(0, y, Math.min(placeholderImage.getWidth(), tmp[0].getWidth()),
                            Math.min(placeholderImage.getHeight(), tmp[0].getHeight()), true);
                }
            });
        } else {
            tmp[0] = downloadedImage.scaledLargerRatio(placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight());
            if (tmp[0].getWidth() > placeholderImage.getWidth()) {
                int diff = tmp[0].getWidth() - placeholderImage.getWidth();
                int x = diff / 2;
                tmp[0] = tmp[0].subImage(x, 0, placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight(), true);
            } else if (tmp[0].getHeight() > placeholderImage.getHeight()) {
                int diff = tmp[0].getHeight() - placeholderImage.getHeight();
                int y = diff / 2;
                tmp[0] = tmp[0].subImage(0, y, Math.min(placeholderImage.getWidth(), tmp[0].getWidth()),
                        Math.min(placeholderImage.getHeight(), tmp[0].getHeight()), true);
            }
        }

        EncodedImage[] image2Return = new EncodedImage[1];
        if (!Display.getInstance().isEdt()) {
            // The image scaling has to be called from EDT
            Display.getInstance().callSeriallyAndWait(() -> {
                Image roundMask = Image.createImage(tmp[0].getWidth(), tmp[0].getHeight(), 0xff000000);
                Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
                gr.setColor(0xffffff);

                gr.fillArc(0, 0, tmp[0].getWidth(), tmp[0].getHeight(), 0, 360);
                Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
                tmp[0] = tmp[0].applyMask(mask);
                image2Return[0] = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tmp[0], false);
            });
        } else {
            Image roundMask = Image.createImage(tmp[0].getWidth(), tmp[0].getHeight(), 0xff000000);
            Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
            gr.setColor(0xffffff);

            gr.fillArc(0, 0, tmp[0].getWidth(), tmp[0].getHeight(), 0, 360);
            Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
            tmp[0] = tmp[0].applyMask(mask);
            image2Return[0] = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tmp[0], false);
        }

        return image2Return[0];

    }
```

In the stacktrace, the NPE seems to stem from the overridden `URLImage.ImageAdapter` :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: create image failed for the given
>   image data of length: 0 at
>   com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:654) at
>   com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternal(EncodedImage.java:365) at
>   com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternalImpl(EncodedImage.java:340)
>   at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getHeight(EncodedImage.java:522) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledLargerRatio(Image.java:899) at
>   com.my.application.ParametresGeneraux$1.lambda$adaptImage$0(ParametresGeneraux.java:564)
>   at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:95) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1154) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1098) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1207) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1244) at
>   com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.actionPerformed(URLImage.java:233)
>   at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:301) at
>   com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:297) at
>   com.codename1.util.CallbackDispatcher.run(CallbackDispatcher.java:53)
>   at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1154) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1098) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:999) at
>   com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120) at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
>   [EDT] 0:0:0,1 - Codename One revisions:
>   e5c43877074c18b4b5c7748d000e5cfac75ab749 2318
>
> [EDT] 0:0:0,1 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.scale(JavaSEPort.java:3996) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Image.scale(Image.java:1007) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledImpl(Image.java:953) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Image.scaled(Image.java:918) at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$71.save(JavaSEPort.java:7659) at
>   com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.scaledEncoded(EncodedImage.java:626) at
>   com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.scaled(EncodedImage.java:653) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledLargerRatio(Image.java:904) at
>   com.my.application.ParametresGeneraux$1.lambda$adaptImage$0(ParametresGeneraux.java:564)
>   at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:95) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1154) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1098) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1207) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1244) at
>   com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.actionPerformed(URLImage.java:233)
>   at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:301) at
>   com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:297) at
>   com.codename1.util.CallbackDispatcher.run(CallbackDispatcher.java:53)
>   at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1154) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1098) at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:999) at
>   com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120) at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Moreover, a glance in the .cn1 directory shows the URLImage storage file name with the suffix "ImageURLTMP" which does not appear when everything works without NPE.

Finally, if I come back to this form later, everything works as expected (images were shown, no NPE). I tried to test for downloadedImage nullness in `imageAdapter` but the EncodedImage is not null.

How can I avoid this NPE?

**Edit March 1st 2017**

Following the answers from @Diamond and @Shai, I believe the NPE occurs because the InfiniteScrollAdapter wants to fill in the screen with rows and consequently launches the download of the same image simultaneously (because it is not in cache). So a solution could be to prevent the InfiniteScrollAdapter to loop (so it becomes finite). How can I do that ?

*Please also note that there is not 404 error, the Network monitor shows response code 200 as depicted below. However the image should not be downloaded 3 times, should it ?*

[image: No 404]

Comment: Post a snippet of the code you used to for your InfinteScroller and URLImage

Comment: I forgot it! See my edit @Diamond!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ImageAdapter to the following:

```
public static final URLImage.ImageAdapter RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK = new URLImage.ImageAdapter() {
    @Override
    public EncodedImage adaptImage(EncodedImage downloadedImage, EncodedImage placeholderImage) {
        Image tmp = downloadedImage.scaledLargerRatio(placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight());
        if (tmp.getWidth() > placeholderImage.getWidth()) {
            int diff = tmp.getWidth() - placeholderImage.getWidth();
            int x = diff / 2;
            tmp = tmp.subImage(x, 0, placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight(), true);
        } else if (tmp.getHeight() > placeholderImage.getHeight()) {
            int diff = tmp.getHeight() - placeholderImage.getHeight();
            int y = diff / 2;
            tmp = tmp.subImage(0, y, Math.min(placeholderImage.getWidth(), tmp.getWidth()),
                    Math.min(placeholderImage.getHeight(), tmp.getHeight()), true);
        }
        Image roundMask = Image.createImage(tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight(), 0xff000000);
        Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
        gr.setColor(0xffffff);
        gr.fillArc(0, 0, tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight(), 0, 360);
        Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
        tmp = tmp.applyMask(mask);
        return EncodedImage.createFromImage(tmp, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAsyncAdapter() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

No need to check `EDT`.

Make sure your `tempPlaceholder` image is applied to your component first and at the end of your logic, call your `URLImage` in a `callSerially()` method:

```
Image tempPlaceholder = Image.createImage(
        ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX,
        ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX,
        ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
Graphics gr = tempPlaceholder.getGraphics();
gr.setAntiAliased(true);
gr.setColor(ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
gr.fillArc(0, 0, ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX, ParametresGeneraux.SIZE_OF_REPORT_PIC_IN_PX, 0, 360);

myComponent.setIcon(tempPlaceholder);


...


//Then call this at the end of everything
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
    EncodedImage roundPlaceholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tempPlaceholder, true);

    final Image reportImage = URLImage.createToStorage(
                        roundPlaceholder,
                        photoFilenameInStorage,
                        currentReport.getPhotoPath(),
                        ParametresGeneraux.RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK
                );
    myComponent.setIcon(reportImage);
    myComponent.getComponentForm().repaint();
});
```

## Edit:

Based on @Shai's answer, you could check if you are currently downloading the same image and prevent another one from being pulled. Because this usually causes a conflict:

```
//Declare this at the top of your class
final static private Map<String, Image> LOADED_URLS = new HashMap<>(); 

//Then change the URLImage image method to this
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
    EncodedImage roundPlaceholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tempPlaceholder, true);

    final Image reportImage = LOADED_URLS.containsKey(photoFilenameInStorage) ? LOADED_URLS.get(photoFilenameInStorage)
                        : URLImage.createToStorage(
                        roundPlaceholder,
                        photoFilenameInStorage,
                        currentReport.getPhotoPath(),
                        ParametresGeneraux.RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK
                );
    LOADED_URLS.put(photoFilenameInStorage, reportImage);
    myComponent.setIcon(reportImage);
    myComponent.getComponentForm().repaint();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Diamond, the check of download in progress makes sense. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Could you explain why it is essential to first apply 'tempPlaceholder` instead of `roundPlaceholder` ? You're right about the fact that pulling from the server a file already being downloaded causes an issue. Indeed what I experience is that the NPE only happens if there is an insufficient number of entries in my database (actually less than 3 on GoogleNexus7 in Portrait orientation). But even with your suggested `LOADED_URLS` the NPE still happens. The best would be to prevent the InfiniteScrollAdapter to display the same element more than once.

Comment: You can use any of the two. Have you checked through Network monitor to see if any of the images in queue returning a `404 error`?

Comment: Thanks @Diamond! Regarding your question, there is no 404 error (see my edits) but the same source file gets downloaded three times (because 3 rows fit on screen), and I believe this is causing the NPE, isn't it ?

Comment: Edit your question to add all your code, I can try to help you debug. Remember to remove sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Diamond. The related part of the code is the `RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK` one because I just found out that if I keep squared image by simply using the `URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL`  instead of `ParametresGeneraux.RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK` the NPE  does not occur anymore and the `InfiniteProgress` stops turning. So it's a good tradeoff for now. When I have time I'll round these images !

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter check if `downloadedImage.getData()` is `null`. I assume it's not and it's a 404 error page or something similar to that.

In that case your adapter can catch the exception and just return a fallback that matches what you expect to see when no image exists.

This works the second time around since the system sees the tmp file and assumes a download is in progress so it doesn't invoke the download code again. The tmp file is later renamed to the final downloadable file.

Comment: Thanks @Shai. As stated in my question, the file DOES exist on server (no 404)! But I guess you meant "it's NOT a 404". Where can I catch the NPE, I cannot find an error method do override in `URLImage` class ?

Comment: Enclosing `tmp[0] = downloadedImage.scaledLargerRatio(placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight()); ` in a try-catch block does catch the NPE. But then the original image on server will "never" (at least until the cache is cleared) be displayed. Is there a way to prevent the `InfiniteScrollAdapter` to display a row more than once ? I could not find any `FiniteScrollAdapter` class.

Comment: If your naming convention for the images is strict (e.g. with a common prefix) you can iterate stored elements and check for TMP files that you can delete. You can also force a refresh by deleting the old image. One of our customers did that automatically on every app startup.

Comment: OK, so prior to instanciating the URLImage with the storageFilename, you suggest to delete any TMP files present, do you ? But the file is downloaded afterwads by the InfiniteSrollAdapter, and the NPE occurs when there are too little rows (so also images) and that the InfiniteScrollAdapter "loops" through the images to fill the screen entirely (if you look at the screencaptures from my question, the round images have all the same source image on the server). Can I prevent the InfiniteScrollAdapter to scroll ? What can I use otherwise ?

Comment: That wasn't so much a "suggestion" as something people do and it's meant to answer the "refresh" question not the general question (which is why it's often best to separate questions to avoid confusion ;-) )

Comment: Ok got it for the refresh, thanks! By the way in my previous comment I meant to prevent the InfiniteScrollAdapter to **loop** not scroll! I'll ask in a separated question!